# In using keras Lambda, how do I handle "TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported"?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm using Keras, and I want to make a layer that takes `[a0, a1]`, `[b0, b1, b2]` as inputs and gives `[a0*b0, a0*b1, a0*b2, a1*b0, a1*b1, a1*b2]` as output. I tried to use `Lambda`, but I couldn't succeed. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Input
from keras.layers import Lambda

def mix(A):
    reshaped = [np.reshape(A[m], (1,np.size(A[m]))) for m in range(len(A))]
    mixed = reshaped[-1]

    for i in range(len(A)-1):
        mixed = np.matmul(np.transpose(reshaped[-i-2]), mixed)
        mixed = np.reshape(mixed, (1,np.size(mixed)))

    return np.reshape(mixed, np.size(mixed))

a = Input(shape=(2,))
b = Input(shape=(3,))
c = Lambda(mix)([a, b])
```

Here's the error I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-07bbf930b48b> in <module>()
      1 a = Input(shape=(2,))
      2 b = Input(shape=(3,))
----> 3 c = Lambda(mix)([a, b])

~\Anaconda3\envs\mind\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    455             # Actually call the layer,
    456             # collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 457             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    458             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
    459 

~\Anaconda3\envs\mind\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py in call(self, inputs, mask)
    685         if has_arg(self.function, 'mask'):
    686             arguments['mask'] = mask
--> 687         return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
    688 
    689     def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):

<ipython-input-31-bbc21320d8af> in mix(A)
      4 
      5     for i in range(len(A)-1):
----> 6         mixed = np.matmul(np.transpose(reshaped[-i-2]), mixed)
      7         mixed = np.reshape(mixed, (1,np.size(mixed)))
      8 

TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported
```

But if I put:

```
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([3,4,5])
print(mix([a,b]))
```

then I get:

```
[ 3  4  5  6  8 10]
```

which is exactly what I intended. But I don't know how to put this in `Lambda` properly.

Can anyone tell me how to handle this? I'm new to Keras, so I don't know the internal structure of `Lambda`, `Input` or other stuffs.

---

Following Abhijit's comment, I changed the code like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Input
from keras.layers import Lambda

def mix(A):
    reshaped = [tf.reshape(A[m], (1,tf.size(A[m]))) for m in range(len(A))]
    mixed = reshaped[-1]

    for i in range(len(A)-1):
        mixed = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(reshaped[-i-2]), mixed)
        mixed = tf.reshape(mixed, (1,tf.size(mixed)))

    return tf.reshape(mixed, [tf.size(mixed)])

a = Input(shape=(2,))
b = Input(shape=(3,))
c = Lambda(mix)([a, b])
```

Now I don't get any errors, but I don't think I got the right neural network. Because executing:

```
model = Model(inputs=[a,b], outputs=c)
print(model.summary())
```

I get:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_22 (InputLayer)           (None, 2)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_23 (InputLayer)           (None, 3)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_3 (Lambda)               (None,)              0           input_22[0][0]                   
                                                                 input_23[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

But see the layer `lambda_3`. Shouldn't the output shape be `(None, 6)`?

Comment: Numpy arrays don't support auto differentiation. Your lambda function must use tensorflow operations, whose derivatives are automatically calculated during backprop. Since your code is straightforward, use tf instead of np and it will work.

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji I followed your comment and got no error. But I think I have another problem. I edited my question. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you need to use Keras backend functions (i.e. `keras.backend.*`) or use backend functions directly (i.e. `tf.*` or `th.*`), I think you are making the definition of `mix` unnecessarily complicated. It can be done much simpler like this:

```
from keras import backend as K

def mix(ts):
    t0 = K.expand_dims(ts[0], axis=-1)
    t1 = K.expand_dims(ts[1], axis=1)
    return K.batch_flatten(t0 * t1)

a = Input(shape=(2,))
b = Input(shape=(3,))
c = Lambda(mix)([a, b])

model = Model(inputs=[a,b], outputs=c)
```

Here is the test:

```
# the reshapes are necessary to make them a batch
a = np.array([1,2]).reshape(1,2)
b = np.array([3,4,5]).reshape(1,3)
print(model.predict([a, b]))

# output
[[ 3.  4.  5.  6.  8. 10.]]
```

Further, sometimes the `Lambda` layer could automatically infer the output shape. However, if you would like you can explicitly set its output shape:

```
c = Lambda(mix, output_shape=(6,))([a, b])
```

Model summary:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_9 (InputLayer)            (None, 2)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_10 (InputLayer)           (None, 3)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_5 (Lambda)               (None, 6)            0           input_9[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_10[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```